# The ring of multipliers is an order

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
I am trying to solve Exercise 12.3 at page 84 in Neukirch, "*Algebraic Number Theory*".
The exercise is following:

> Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$.
>   Let $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ ($\alpha_i \in K$) be a basis of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
>   \begin{align*}
>   M = \mathbb{Z}\alpha_1 + \dots + \mathbb{Z}\alpha_n, \\
>   \O = \{ \alpha \in K \mid \alpha M \subset M \}.
> \end{align*}
>   Show that $\O$ is an order of $K$.
>   ($\O$ is called a *ring of multipliers*.)

An *order* is a subring of $\O_K$
which is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n$.
I tried to find a basis of $\O$, but I can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Show that there is $d>0$ such that $d\mathcal O_K\subseteq M\subseteq(1/d)\mathcal O_K$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
Thanks. I found $d$ such that $dM \subset \O_K$, but I haven't found such that $d\O_K \subset M$ yet.
However, it seems to be a expression about not $\O$ but $\O_K$.
Can I learn about $\O$ from this expression?

Comment: $a\in\mathcal O_K\implies(ad^2)M\subset (ad^2)(1/d)\mathcal O_K\subset d(a\mathcal O_K)\subset d\mathcal O_K\subset M\implies ad^2\in\mathcal O\implies d^2\mathcal O_K\subset\mathcal O$

Comment: $\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
I see, and I found $d$ by using Lemma 2.9 of "ANT". 
Take $d'$ such that $\alpha_i' := d'\alpha_i \in \O_K$, 
let $d''$ be the discriminant of $\alpha_1', \dots, \alpha_n'$, 
then $d = d'd''$.
Thanks.